# Conan, CMake.test() generate XML report

Tags: c++, conan

I am currently in the process of introducing Conan.io (Version 1.20.5) to my project.

With Cmake.test(), I am missing the XML testreport that was previously generated by calling `ctest -T test` directly.

Here is the conanfile.py build() excerpt:

```
def build(self):
  cmake = CMake(self)
  cmake.configure()
  cmake.build()
  cmake.test()
```

Comments:

1.) Defining args to the build() is breaking the build as these args seem to be forwarded to _build(): https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/812c8ec8185e24b2bc41fb6e855d35c925526670/conans/client/build/cmake.py#L276

Regards, Christian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to pass an argument to `ctest`, but Conan calls `cmake --build . --target test` instead of `ctest` directly, thus you need to pass as extra argument:

```
def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()
    cmake.test(args=['--', 'ARGS=-T Test'])
```

This will result in the follow command:

```
> cmake --build '/tmp/foo/test_package/build/878b1b6e2d4cbc82452d014e37c38868584457e8' '--target' 'test' 'ARGS=-T Test' '--' '-j4'
```

Now you will have the XML file result.

Regards!

Comment: Hm. I am getting ```ConanExeption: Error 1 while executing... ```  the resulting cmake call looks like your example tho.

Comment: Could you please, add details about your error? Conan version, command line, recipe, log, ... My example works perfectly for a regular recipe

Comment: The proposed solution works only on linux, but errors on Windows `MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: ARGS=-T Test
`. Is there a Windows alternative?

Comment: Did you try by passing with quotes? `ARGS="-T Test"`

Comment: I successfully get the xml report generated. However, it lies in the build folder temporarily created in my conan local cache. How can we programmatically get it from this location ?

Answer (score 1):

For conan 2.0 the parameter to `cmake.test()` is `cli_args` and CTest now accepts `--output-junit` so I have:

```
    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        cmake.test(cli_args=["ARGS=--output-junit testing/results.xml"])
```